# Prove Or Disprove A Set Statement

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

So I saw this very trick question. Prove or disprove:

$$S=\left \{ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k(k+1)}:n\in \mathbb{N} \right \}$$

$$T=\left \{\frac{m-1}{m}:m \in \mathbb{N} \right \}$$

Prove or disprove $S = T$. I tried to use different numbers and so far it is looking to be the same. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: The are equal. Use the fact that $\frac 1 {k(k+1)}=\frac  1k -\frac  1 {k+1}$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy someone said also that they are not equal. So are they? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the @Kavi's comment, notice that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k(k+1)}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right) $$ so

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k(k+1)}=\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}=1-\frac{1}{n+1}$$ therefore $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k(k+1)}=\frac{n}{n+1} $$

Well, indeed $T$ and $S$ are not the same, as the elements of $T$ are $$0,1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3},\frac{3}{4},\cdots  $$, and the elements of $S$ are $$1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3},\frac{3}{4},\cdots    $$ you couldn't get $0$ in $S$ as there is no way to sum positive values and get 0. To see why $1\in S$,  take the limit $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k(k+1)}=1$$ similarly $1\in T$ because $$ \lim_{m\to\infty} \frac{m-1}{m}=1$$ The sets are equal if $n\geq 2$.

Comment: someone said also that they are equal everywhere, not just m >=2. So are they? Thank you.

Comment: @SneakAttr if $n\geq 2$ I have updated it